# Mouse events on WindowsFormsHost hosting video are not fired in WPF

Tags: wpf, mouseevent, windowsformshost

I have a WPF application hosting an ActiveX object streaming video using the WindowsFormsHost. Since activeX objects always render on top of the application, I am unable to handle mouse events because the activeX object is swallowing these events and not raising them for the host to handle.

Is there a way to capture the mouse events?